# Objects loose interaction after moving first time

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a constructor and have some problems with fabricjs, looks like a bug.

I have a number of objects like in a fabricjs example: http://fabricjs.com/stickman/

I have some points (circle=Array(); circle[i]=new Fabric.Circle({...}) and lines, connected with them (var line=new Fabric.Line({...}); circle[i].line=line;)

I let user to draw some figure with points and then I want to let him edit this figure like a stickman from an example.

But I have a certain rule: horizontal lines should stay horizontal, vertical lines should stay vertical and dimensions of lines after the point we edit should be remained.

So, I catch an element with

canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    var p = e.target;

Then I change previous and next lines (according the rule) and then (SIC!) I change coordinates of all other points (I change circle[i].left and circle[i].top according the rule).

And after that points are redrawn, but actually canvas still think that they are at their previous coordinates! (I cannot select points which I see but I can select some empty space the point were before)

Here I catch the object user wants to move:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    var p = e.target;
    var x2;
    var y2;
    var type;


    if (p.line1) type=p.line1.type;
    else type=p.line2.type;

    if (type==1)
      {
        x2=p.left;
        y2=p.y;
      }
    if (type==2)
      {
        x2=p.x;
        y2=p.top;
      }
    if (type==3)
      {
        var delta=Math.sqrt((p.top-p.y)*(p.top-p.y)+(p.left-p.x)*(p.left-p.x));
        if (p.left>p.x)
        x2=p.x+delta;
         else x2=p.x-delta;
        if (p.top<p.y)
            y2=p.y-delta;
            else y2=p.y+delta;
       }

     p.left=x2;
     p.top=y2;
     p=fix_point(p);
     points=reorder(points,p.id);

    });
```

`

Here is fix_point(p):

```
 function fix_point (p)
     {

     if (p.line1)
     {
       p.line1.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
       if (p.line1.type==1)
         {
         p.line1.line1.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top+3 });
         p.line1.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top-3 });
           }
         else
         {
          p.line1.line1.set({ 'x1': p.left+3, 'y1': p.top });
          p.line1.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left-3, 'y1': p.top });
             }
      }
     if (p.line2)
    {  p.line2.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
        if (p.line2.type==1)
         {
         p.line2.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top+3 });
         p.line2.line2.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top-3 });
           }
         else
         {
          p.line2.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left+3, 'y2': p.top });
          p.line2.line2.set({ 'x2': p.left-3, 'y2': p.top });
             }
       }
     return p;
     }
```

Here is reorder (points, id):

```
function reorder(points, id)
{

   points[id].fill='green';
   var x2;
   var y2;
   var m;
   var delta;
    for (var k=id; k<points.length-2; k++)
    {
     points[k+1].fill='yellow';
     if (points[k].line2)
      {
        if (points[k].line2.type==1)
         {  if (points[k+1].top!=points[k].top)
               {x2=points[k+1].left;
                y2=points[k].top;
                 }
             else
             {  delta=points[k].left-points[k].x;
                    x2=points[k+1].left+delta;
                    y2=points[k+1].top;

             }

          }
        if (points[k].line2.type==2)
        {

            if (points[k+1].left!=points[k].left)
               {x2=points[k].left;
                y2=points[k+1].top;
                 }
             else
             {  delta=points[k].top-points[k].y;
                    x2=points[k+1].left;
                    y2=points[k+1].top+delta;

             }
         }
         if (points[k].line2.type==3)
          {
          if ((points[k].line1)&&(points[k].line1.type==1))
              {
                delta=points[k].left-points[k].x;
                x2=points[k+1].left+delta;
                y2=points[k+1].top;
              }

            if ((points[k].line1)&&(points[k].line1.type==2))
              {
                delta=points[k].top-points[k].y;
                x2=points[k+1].left;
                y2=points[k+1].top+delta;
              }
          } 

       if (x2<0) x2=0;
       if (y2<0) y2=0;
       if (x2>500) x2=500;
       if (y2>500) y2=500;
       points[k+1].left=x2;
       points[k+1].top=y2;
       canvas.renderAll();
      }
    }

    for (var k=id; k<points.length-1; k++)
    {
     points[k].x=points[k].left;
     points[k].y=points[k].top;
     points[k].text.left=points[k].left+10;
     points[k].text.top=points[k].top;
     points[k]=fix_point(points[k]);
         }
  return points;
}
```

You can try here: `jsfiddle.net/Lasana/bwdoy5v1/`

First press DRAW and put some points. End with doubleclick. Then press EDIT - you will see all points red and numbered. Try to change some point at the and of horizontal or vertical line. And then look at the canvas! Green and red points are available to select.

Yellow points are drawn on their new place, but can be selected clicked on their old place - empty space! But if I find that empty space - I can edit this point too...

I cannot understand what is this? :)))))

How I can fix it?...

Comment: Can you post your code so SO user will be able help you

Comment: code is too long..
actually, it is here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lasana/bwdoy5v1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common mistake in fabricjs is to modify the objects `top` and `left` and do not use obj.setCoords();

This will not allow for further mouse interaction after the first edit.
Please see the attached snippet, copy of your fiddle.
I just added at the end of the `reorder` function a `point[k].setCoords()` call.

```js
      var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('c',{ selection: false });
      var start=0;
      var cur=0;
      var i=0;
      var xcoord=[];
      var ycoord=[];
      var points=[];
      var lines=[];

      var DrawMode = document.getElementById('draw'),
      EditMode = document.getElementById('edit');

      DrawMode.onclick=Drawing;
      EditMode.onclick=Editing;

      var drawline=new fabric.Line([0,0,0,0], {stroke: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)'});
      canvas.add(drawline);

   
    function putPoint(x,y)
      {
        var point=new fabric.Circle({
         radius: 7,
         fill: '#fff',
         stroke: '#000',
         originX: 'center',
         originY: 'center',
         strokeWidth: 4,
         left: x,
         top: y
            });
         point.hasControls = point.hasBorders = point.selectable = false;
         point.x=x;
         point.y=y;
         point.id=0;


         return point;
    }

    function goStraight(x1, x2, y1, y2)
     {
   
         if ((Math.abs(x2-x1)>0)&&(Math.abs(y2-y1)==0))
         {
         if (x2>x1)
              { x1=x1+5;}
           else
              { x1=x1-5;}

            var line=new fabric.Line([x2,y2,x1,y1],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
            var line1=new fabric.Line([x2,y2+3,x1,y1+3],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
            var line2=new fabric.Line([x2,y2-3,x1,y1-3],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
            line.type=1;
           }

         if ((Math.abs(x2-x1)==0)&&(Math.abs(y2-y1)>0))
          {

         if (y2>y1)
             {y1=y1+5;}
           else
             {y1=y1-5;}


             var line=new fabric.Line([x2,y2,x1,y1],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
             var line1=new fabric.Line([x2+3,y2,x1+3,y1],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
             var line2=new fabric.Line([x2-3,y2,x1-3,y1],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
             line.type=2;
          }


         if (Math.abs(x2-x1)==Math.abs(y2-y1))
           {
         if (x2>x1)
              { x1=x1+5;}
           else
              { x1=x1-5;}

            var line=new fabric.Line([x2,y2,x1,y1],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
            var line1=new fabric.Line([x2,y2+3,x1,y1+3],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
            var line2=new fabric.Line([x2,y2-3,x1,y1-3],{stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});
            line.type=3;
           }

         line.hasControls = line.hasBorders = line.selectable = false;
         line1.hasControls = line1.hasBorders = line1.selectable = false;
         line2.hasControls = line2.hasBorders = line2.selectable = false;

         var start=new fabric.Circle({originX:'center', originY:'center', radius: 4, left:x1, top: y1, fill: 'blue'});
         start.hasControls=false;

         line.line1=line1;
         line.line2=line2;
         line.start=start;


         return line;

    }

   function joinPoint(point, lineleft, lineright)
            {
            point.line1=lineleft;
            point.line2=lineright;

            return point;
            }

    function DrawPoint(event)
     {
  
     var CX = event.offsetX==undefined?event.layerX:event.offsetX;  // x2
     var CY = event.offsetY==undefined?event.layerY:event.offsetY;  // y2

     var x1=xcoord[cur-1];  // x1
     var y1=ycoord[cur-1];  // y1
     var newx=CX;
     var newy=CY;


   //  *(0,0)                Y
   //                        |             Z
   //                  1     | 1     2   /
   //                        |         /
   //                        |       /   2
   //           6        y2  |------------ *
   //                        |   /         |
   //                        | /           |    3
   //   ---------------------*-------------------------X
   //           6          / |x1,y1        x2
   //                    /   |
   //                5 /     |                 3
   //                /  5    |
   //              /         |
   //            /         4 |    4
   //                        |
   //                        |
   //
   //

     var x=CX-x1;
     var y=y1-CY;

     var type=0;

  
     if ((x>=0)&&(y>=0))
       {
        if (y<=0.5*x)
          type=3;
        if ((y>0.5*x)&&(y<2*x))
          type=2;
        if (y>=2*x)
          type=1;

       }


     if ((x>=0)&&(y<0))
        {
         if (Math.abs(y)<x)
           type=3;
         else
           type=4;
        }


     if ((x<0)&&(y<0))
       {
        if (Math.abs(y)<0.5*Math.abs(x))
            type=6;
        if ((Math.abs(y)>=0.5*Math.abs(x))&&(Math.abs(y)<=2*Math.abs(x)))
            type=5;
        if (Math.abs(y)>2*Math.abs(x))
           type=4;
        }


     if ((x<0)&&(y>=0))
       {
        if (Math.abs(x)<y)
           type=1;
         else
           type=6;
       }

     if ((type==1)||(type==4))
        {
         newx=x1;
         newy=CY;
        }

     if ((type==3)||(type==6))
        {
         newx=CX;
         newy=y1;
        }

      if ((type==2)||(type==5))
         {

        var d=0.5*Math.abs(x-y);
        if (type==2)
          {
           if (Math.abs(CX-x1)>=Math.abs(CY-y1))
             {
              newx=CX-d;
              newy=CY-d;
             }
            else
              {
               newx=CX+d;
               newy=CY+d;
              }

           }

        else
          {
           if (Math.abs(CX-x1)>=Math.abs(CY-y1))
             {
              newx=CX+d;
              newy=CY+d;
             }
            else
              {
               newx=CX-d;
               newy=CY-d;
              }
          }


         }

        xcoord[cur]=newx;
        ycoord[cur]=newy;
        points[i]=putPoint(newx,newy);

        if (start>1)
        { 
         var XPREV=xcoord[cur-1];
         var YPREV=ycoord[cur-1];

         lines[i-1]=goStraight(XPREV,newx,YPREV,newy);
         canvas.add(lines[i-1],lines[i-1].line1,lines[i-1].line2,points[i]);

         points[i]=joinPoint(points[i],lines[i-1],null);
         if (i>1) {
                 points[i-1]=joinPoint(points[i-1],lines[i-2],lines[i-1]);
                 points[i-1].id=i-1;
                 }
           else points[0]=joinPoint(points[0],null,lines[0]);
         i++;
         cur++;
          }

        else
         {
         if (start==1)
          {
           var xline=new fabric.Line([0, CY, 700, CY], { stroke: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.3)' } );
           var yline=new fabric.Line([CX, 0, CX, 700], { stroke: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)' } );
           var zline=new fabric.Line([CX-350, CY+350, CX+350, CY-350], { stroke: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)' } );

            xline.set('selectable', false);
           yline.set('selectable', false);
            zline.set('selectable', false);
            canvas.add(xline, yline, zline, points[i]);

            points[i]=joinPoint(points[i],null,null);

            start++;
            i++;
            cur++;
          }
          else
             start++;
           }

    }


    function DrawLine(event)
    {
     if (start>1)
       {

         var CX = event.offsetX==undefined?event.layerX:event.offsetX;
            var CY = event.offsetY==undefined?event.layerY:event.offsetY;
            var X=xcoord[cur-1];
            var Y=ycoord[cur-1];
            var color='';

            if (Math.abs(CX-X)<Math.abs(CY-Y))
                color='rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
                else  color='rgba(0,0,255,0.3)';
            if ((Math.abs(Math.abs(CX-X)-Math.abs(CY-Y))<75)&&((CX-X)*(CY-Y)<0))
                     color='rgba(255,0,0,0.3)';
            drawline.set({'x1': CX, 'y1': CY, 'x2': X, 'y2': Y, stroke: color });
            canvas.renderAll();

                 }


    }

    function StopLine(event)
    {
     cur=0;
     start=0;
     xcoord=[];
     ycoord=[];

    }

     function Editing ()
     {
      cur=0;

      canvas.defaultCursor='default';
      var n=points.length
      canvas.remove(points[n-1]);
      canvas.remove(points[n-1].line1);
      canvas.remove(points[n-1].line1.line1);
      canvas.remove(points[n-1].line1.line2);
      var text;
      var strokes=new Array();
     
       for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
         points[i].selectable=true;
         points[i].fill='red';
         text=new fabric.Text('№ '+points[i].id, {left: points[i].left+10, top: points[i].top, fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Century Gothic'});
         points[i].text=text;
         points[i].text.selectable=false;
         canvas.add(points[i].text);

        }
      document.removeEventListener('click', DrawPoint);
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', DrawLine);
      document.removeEventListener('dblclick', StopLine);

      canvas.renderAll();


     function fix_point (p)
     {

     if (p.line1)
     {
       p.line1.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
       if (p.line1.type==1)
         {
         p.line1.line1.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top+3 });
         p.line1.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top-3 });
           }
         else
         {
          p.line1.line1.set({ 'x1': p.left+3, 'y1': p.top });
          p.line1.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left-3, 'y1': p.top });
             }
      }
     if (p.line2)
    {  p.line2.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
        if (p.line2.type==1)
         {
         p.line2.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top+3 });
         p.line2.line2.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top-3 });
           }
         else
         {
          p.line2.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left+3, 'y2': p.top });
          p.line2.line2.set({ 'x2': p.left-3, 'y2': p.top });
             }
       }
     return p;
     }



    function reorder(points, id)
    {
      
       points[id].fill='green';
       var x2;
       var y2;
       var m;
       var delta;
      for (var k=id; k<points.length-2; k++)
     {
      points[k+1].fill='yellow';
      if (points[k].line2)
       {
        if (points[k].line2.type==1)
         { if (points[k+1].top!=points[k].top)
             {x2=points[k+1].left;
              y2=points[k].top;
               }
           else
           {  delta=points[k].left-points[k].x;
              x2=points[k+1].left+delta;
              y2=points[k+1].top;

           }

              }
         if (points[k].line2.type==2)
         {
         
          if (points[k+1].left!=points[k].left)
             {x2=points[k].left;
              y2=points[k+1].top;
               }
           else
           {  delta=points[k].top-points[k].y;
              x2=points[k+1].left;
              y2=points[k+1].top+delta;

           }
         }
             if (points[k].line2.type==3)
              {
              if ((points[k].line1)&&(points[k].line1.type==1))
                 {
                  delta=points[k].left-points[k].x;
                  x2=points[k+1].left+delta;
                  y2=points[k+1].top;

                 }

                if ((points[k].line1)&&(points[k].line1.type==2))
                 {
                  delta=points[k].top-points[k].y;
                  x2=points[k+1].left;
                  y2=points[k+1].top+delta;

                 }

              }

          
           if (x2<0) x2=0;
           if (y2<0) y2=0;
           if (x2>500) x2=500;
           if (y2>500) y2=500;
           points[k+1].left=x2;
           points[k+1].top=y2;
           points[k].setCoords();
           canvas.renderAll();

       }

     }


        for (var k=id; k<points.length-1; k++)
        {
         points[k].x=points[k].left;
         points[k].y=points[k].top;
         points[k].text.left=points[k].left+10;
         points[k].text.top=points[k].top;
         points[k]=fix_point(points[k]);
        
        }
      return points;
    }


    canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    var p = e.target;
    var x2;
    var y2;
    var type;


    if (p.line1) type=p.line1.type;
    else type=p.line2.type;

    if (type==1)
      {
       x2=p.left;
       y2=p.y;
      }
    if (type==2)
      {
       x2=p.x;
       y2=p.top;
      }
    if (type==3)
      {
        var delta=Math.sqrt((p.top-p.y)*(p.top-p.y)+(p.left-p.x)*(p.left-p.x));
        if (p.left>p.x)
        x2=p.x+delta;
         else x2=p.x-delta;
        if (p.top<p.y)
           y2=p.y-delta;
           else y2=p.y+delta;
       }

     p.left=x2;
     p.top=y2;
     p=fix_point(p);
     points=reorder(points,p.id);

    });



     canvas.renderAll();

     }

     function Drawing ()
     {

     canvas.defaultCursor='crosshair';
     document.addEventListener('click', DrawPoint, false);
     document.addEventListener('mousemove', DrawLine, false);
     document.addEventListener('dblclick', StopLine, false);


       }
```

```html
<script src="http://www.fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
  
<div style="display: block; max-width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 40px; background-color: #808080; color: #FFF">
      Please, click DRAW to put some points. Doubleclick - stop drawing. Then click EDIT <br><br>
   <div style="display: block; width: 700px; height: 50px; margin: 0 auto">
      <button id="draw">Draw</button>
      <button id="edit">Edit</button>
      
   </div>

   
    <div style="display: block; width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #FFF">
     <canvas id="c" width=500 height=500>
```